# Firestore returns a document even though none exists

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using the web API, Typescript, no other libraries.
I've set up a very simple database. Users sign up with email/password and a doc is added to a `/users` collection with their uid as the key. When a user logs in I check their uid against the `/users` collection and return the relevant doc.

I've been messing with security rules, checking my logic and regularly manually deleting users and data via the Firebase console as I go.
I don't know if something has got confused but now my database is completely empty according to the console Data tab - there is no `/users` collection or anything else - but when I run...

`` this.db.doc(`users/${firebase.auth().currentUser.uid}`).get() ``

...I get a document back that has the correct id (matches my registered user id) but the `exists` property is `false`. Where is this coming from?

As the database is empty I'm assuming its from some kind of local cache?
Or have I confused things or got out of sync by manually deleting data?
Can I clear that cache, or do I have to do an extra check for `exists:false`

Cheers all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I get a document back that has the correct id (matches my registered user id) but the exists property is false. Where is this coming from?

You will **always** get a DocumentSnapshot for any single-document `get()`.  That's just the way it works.  You definitely have to check the exists flag (or see that `data()` returns an object) to know if there is any data in that snapshot.  It's not really any more complicated than that.

Comment: @shn: I understand the question in the same way as Doug did here. A [`DocumentReferenceget()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#get) call always returns a `DocumentSnapshot` object, even if no document exists in the database (or cache). **If** indeed no such document exists, the `exists` property of the `DocumentSnapshot` is `false.

Comment: Ah ok, so the fact that the id matches the request is just because it is returning based on that request, not because it has some kind of cached version of an older instance. That makes sense (I think) and might even explain another weird bit of behaviour I was seeing. I'm on something else now but will check this tonight in my build.

Comment: The ID in the DocumentSnapshot is always going to be exactly what you used in the DocumentReference.  Note that a a DocumentSnapshot is also used in query results where you don't know the IDs ahead of time.  In that context, the ID is a more helpful piece of information.

Comment: Yeah, it's all starting to make sense now. Kinda :) Cheers for the answer. I'm sure I'll be back with more soon.